# Why Int8.max &+ Int8.max equals to "-2"?

Tags: swift, binary, integer, overflow, standard-library

Following Swift Standard Library [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2964457), `&+` discards any bits that overflow the fixed width of the integer type. I just did not get **why adding two maximum values, 8-bit signed integer can hold results in -2**:

```swift
/// Two max Int8 values (127 each, 8-bit group)
let x6 = Int8.max
let x7 = Int8.max

/// Prints `1 1 1 1 1 1 1`
String(Int8.max, radix: 2)

/// Here we get `-2` in decimal system
let x8 = x6 &+ x7

/// Prints `-1 0`
String(x8, radix: 2)
```

If we break down the binary calculation we will get this:

```
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
+   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
-----------------------------
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0

Which is -126, as the leftmost bit is a negative sign.
```

Why does Swift discards any bits except the rightmost two (`1` and `0`). Did I miss some overflow rules? I've read some pieces of knowledge in the web, but did not get closed to cracking this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift (and every other programming language I know) uses [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed integers, rather than [sign-and-magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) as you seem to assume.

In the 2's complement representation, the leftmost `1` does not represent "a negative sign". You can think of it as representing -128, so the `Int8` value of -2 would be represented as 1111 1110 (-128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2).

OTOH, -126 would be represented as 1000 0010 (-128 + 2).

Comment: @DmitryAksyonov Hmm, that _is_ a bit unclear isn't it? I meant to say "negative" in the sense that it doesn't represent the `-` sign. Hopefully it's clearer after the edit :)

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification. I found out that I should study this thing of 2's complement, as for now I am completely out of subject.

Comment: oh yes I got it, this just represent the negative value (e.g. `(2 pow n)* -1`), but thanks for it too:)

BTW, I think that's a very good [piece](https://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs452/Lec/L03SlidesF14.pdf) on 2's complement which I'm now going thorough (pages 17-33). Just look how deep it is, wow.